# Why is there segmentation fault (core dumped) error showing up at compile time when I am trying to insert data into the nodes in linked list

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct  Node*  head=  (struct Node*)  malloc  (sizeof (struct Node));
struct  Node*  second =  (struct Node*)  malloc (sizeof (struct Node));

head->data=1;
second=head->next;
second->data=2;
second->next='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line: second=head->next;
This is giving the segmentation fault as the value on the right is assigned to the value on the left by '=' operator

So, instead try using:
head->next=second;